# A2 reinitialization of date component

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-routing, daterangepicker

I am working on Angular 2 project in which I need to use this date range picker:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker

A date picker constist of a set of options represented by a json object that we pass trough a template. For example:

> input type="datepicker" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" ...>

I want to allow user to translate the website by choosing the one language from the list (translation is done, everything working fine except date picker).

The idea is that we translate the calendar once user select a new language (which should be simple as just updating the json object that represents an options myDatePickerOptions). However, when I update settings nothing changes.

I come to the conclusion that, once initialized, date picker couldn't be changed. Therefore, I thought the way to achieve my goal is to re-initialize component, re-render or whatever you want to call it.

My question is how do I re-initialize the child component (so the construct, ngoninit and all other stuff get called).

Comment: what do you mean by `re-initialization`?

Comment: Hi @maximus - I need to re-call the constructor method and ngoninit. From some reason, I cannot update my date picker component by changing it's settings (when user select other language on website, I need to translate calendar). The only way I could do that is through changing the view (because when I switch to another view, my date component initializes again). Therefore, something is forcing my date picker to update it's value..

Comment: do you add this component dynamically? if not, you can wrap your component into `ngIf` and toggle it. `ngIf` destroys the view and reinitializes it again

Comment: @maximus good point but I do not want to show/hide anything. Look, when I pick a language from the language picker, I need to translate the calendar. Right now, once my calendar is initialized - the settings couldn't be changed which means that I cannot translate it via calendar settings at the point when user clicks on a new language. However, I noticed that calendar changes applied only when switching through views (when date component (which is a child component) re-initializes again).

Comment: sorry, too much details, maybe make a question more specific or put up a plunker

Comment: I did explain it now. See on the top @maximus

Comment: do you change `myDatePickerOptions` completely or mutate it inside, i.e. 
 modify its property?

Comment: @Maximus I tried both ways without any luck. What's the difference anyways?

Comment: well, create a plunker. the difference is that angular doesn't track object mutations, only reference change

Comment: @Maximus ngIf actually did the work since it, as you mentioned, destroys and reinitializes the component depends on the ngIf state. If you want you can post a reply to my problem so I can approve your answer. Thanks!

Comment: just posted the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the components are referenced in templates and not added dynamically you don't have a reference to the `componentRef` to destroy a view. But `ngIf` can do that so you can use it to re-initialize the component like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="toggle">
    <input type="text" name="daterangeInput" daterangepicker [options]="options" (selected)="selectedDate($event)">
</ng-container>
```